# Rcpp installation

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools, install.packages

I just updated R to 3.4.0 and RStudio to 1.0.143, and I reinstalled some packages. Everything was ok except for Rcpp (and packages which require Rccp), I got this :

```
> install.packages("Rcpp")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary  source needs_compilation
Rcpp 0.12.10 0.12.11              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘Rcpp’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2485092 bytes (2.4 MB)
downloaded 2.4 MB

'\\CXXXX0001\Users\RXXXXn'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
'\\CXXXX0001\Users\RXXXXn\R\R-3.4.0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"//CXXXX0001/Users/RXXXn/R/R-3.4.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "\\CXXXX0001\Users\RXXXXn\R\R-3.4.0\library" C:\Users\RXXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmOL8r0/downloaded_packages/Rcpp_0.12.11.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\RXXXXn\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmOL8r0\downloaded_packages’
```

I restarted my R session before doing this, so there should be no conflict of loaded packages.

What can I do ?

**EDIT** after user3293236 comment

I also have a problem with `devtools` package...

```
> install.packages("devtools")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/devtools_1.13.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 440923 bytes (430 KB)
downloaded 430 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘\\CXXXX0001\Users\RXXXXn\R\R-3.4.0\library\file16401ac3a13\devtools’ to ‘\\CXXXX0001\Users\RXXXXn\R\R-3.4.0\library\devtools’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\RXXXXn\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmOL8r0\downloaded_packages
> library(devtools)
Error in library(devtools) : aucun package nommé ‘devtools’ n'est trouvé
```

Comment: Do you have Rtools installed?

Comment: Yes, Rtools 3.4.0.1964

Comment: My guess would be there's something going on with your `PATH`.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @MrSnake Try `devtools::find_rtools()` what does it return?

Comment: @user3293236 I have also a problem with devtools (see edit)

Comment: `devtools` is not installed. Try `install.packages("devtools")`.

Comment: @MrSnake Can you check if you actually have writing rights in your R path? It seems the packages cannot be moved where they belong

Comment: @MrSnake This sounds like a permissions issue. Try applying some of the solutions in [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Br%5D+unable+to+move+temporary+installation).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue while trying to set up someone else's computer. Brand new R installation (R version 3.4.1) but R was installed in a OneDrive folder. I also thought it was a permissions thing (as @nrussell commented) as the error was the same `... unable to move temporary installation ...`.

I had no issue installing `devtools` as normal (or any other packages) and even with Rtools installed `Rcpp` would not install by install.packages("Rcpp")`. Interestingly,

`install.packages("Rcpp", type = 'source')`

Did work after some compiling. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem so, I installed a previous Rcpp release and worked.

```
install_version("Rcpp", version = "1.0.3", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Answer (score 0):

What can you do?  I would start by reading the error messages.

It clearly showed you that you are offered a different *source* and *binary* version. For the former you need tools. That is abundantly documented.

And by tomorrow CRAN will also have a new binary version for you. But with a new release made hours ago, you need to wait a moment. Or make your system capable of installing from source.